# Vue não trabalha com ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, vue.js

Sou novo no Vue e fiz um código simples:

```
var appCtrlUsuario = new Vue({
el: '#appCtrlUsuario',
data: {
    Nome: '',
    Email: '',
    Cond: '',
    Type: [{ id: 1, name: 'Morador' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Síndico - Rensponsável' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Administradora - Rensponsável' },
    { id: 4, name: 'Zelador – Rensponsável' },
    ],
    select: null
},
methods: {
    cadastrar: function () {
        var data = {
            "UserCondominio": this.Cond,
            "UserEmail": this.Email,
            "UserName": this.Nome,
            "UserType": this.select
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:51541/Api.svc/cadastro-usuario",

            data: data,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (result) {
                Swal.fire({
                    type: 'success',
                    title: 'Sucesso!',
                    text: 'Adicionado!'
                });
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                Swal.fire({
                    type: 'error',
                    title: 'Erro!',
                    text: this.statusText
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
 });
```

Quando eu clico com os forms vazio cai em error no ajax e apareça o sweet alert aparece, mas quando eu preencho com dados a página pisca e os models voltam a ficar zerados e o ajax nunca retorna. Aqui está o html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
      <title>Cadastro de Usuário</title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@8"></script>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
​
      <header class="w3-container w3-teal">
          <h1>Cadastro de Usuario</h1>
      </header>
      <div class="w3-container w3-half w3-margin-top" id="appCtrlUsuario">
    ​
          <form class="w3-container w3-card-4">
        <p>
            <input v-model="Nome" class="w3-input" type="text" style="width:90%" required>
            <label>Nome</label>
        </p>
        <p>
            <input v-model="Email" class="w3-input" type="text" style="width:90%" required>
            <label>Email</label>
        </p>
        <p>
            <input v-model="Cond" class="w3-input" type="text" style="width:90%" required>
            <label>Condomínio</label>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>Tipo</label>
            <select v-model="select">
                <option v-for="item in Type" :value="item.id">{{item.name}}</option>
            </select>
        </p>
        ​ ​ ​
        <p>
            <button v-on:click="cadastrar" class="w3-button w3-section w3-teal w3-ripple"> Cadastrar </button>
        </p>
        ​
          </form>
    ​
      </div>
<script src="scripts/controller.js"></script>​

  </body>
  </html>
```

Alguém sabe o que está errado?

Comment: O que diz a tab `network` das ferramentas de programador do browser (devtools)?

Comment: Mas pq utilizar jQuery para fazer requisição http com Vue, aliás para que utilizar jQuery com Vue?? Pode utilizar axios que é muito mais indicado pra isso: https://github.com/axios/axios

Comment: Na verdade eu estava usando XMLHttpRequest puro e tendo este problema, daí pensei em usar o jquery. Não tentei o axios ainda. Quanto ao erro da network é: nenhum!! Nada aparece no console, nada aparece na network!!

Answer (score 0):

Até que dá sim, mas vai dar um trabalhão, use o Axios que é uma biblioteca JS pra fazer requisições ajax

```
axios.post('http://localhost:51541/Api.svc/cadastro-usuario', data)
.then(function(response){
  //caso dê certo
}).catch(function(error){
  //caso dê errado
})
```

Comment: Eu usei o axios mas nada. Troquei o vue por knockout e foi. O mais estranho é que nada aparece no console nem na aba de rede do navegador. Enfim o meu problema foi resolvido trocando o framework javascript.